# C# or SQL filtering/Sorting

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to sort and filter Data coming in from a database either using C# or SQL. From the database I will receive two columns of data, a part number (Letter/Number) and price data (Number). e.g.

[image]

What I need is a the lowest price data from each Part number letter, so the cheapest A, cheapest B etc. The results will be put in a datagridview element.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share any attempt that you've made at solving this problem independently.

Comment: Group by part, take lowest value from each group.

Answer (score 2):

`SQL` wise, could be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Part,1,1),MIN(Price) FROM myTable GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Part,1,1)
```

Comment: The grouping should be done based on the part number letter, not the entire part number.

Comment: @itsme86, Thank you for the correction had not notice it. Edited